# How to create a mask from Polygons (processing)?

Tags: processing, polygon, mask

I am trying to create from a custom shape a mask for an image.
In processing I came up with this:

```java
Image img;
PImage img2;
PGraphics mGraphic;

void setup(){
 img = loadImage("mask.jpg");
 img2 = loadImage("test.jpg");
 mGraphic = createGraphics(1024,1024, JAVA2D);
 size(img.width, img.height);
}

void draw(){
  background(255);

  mGraphic.beginDraw();
  mGraphic.background(0); 
  mGraphic.ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 400, 400); 
  mGraphic.endDraw();

  img2.mask(mGraphic);
  image(img2,0,0);

}
```

Above code will create a ellipse that will be the mask of the image. 
I would like to achieve the same with a custom shape generated by Polygons:

```java
import java.awt.Polygon;

PImage img;
PImage img2;
PGraphics mGraphic;

CustomShape myShape = new CustomShape();

void setup(){
 img = loadImage("mask.jpg");
 img2 = loadImage("test.jpg");
 mGraphic = createGraphics(1024,1024, JAVA2D);

  myShape.addPoint(25, 25);
  myShape.addPoint(275, 25);
  myShape.addPoint(275, 75);
  myShape.addPoint(175, 75);
  myShape.addPoint(175, 275);
  myShape.addPoint(125, 275);
  myShape.addPoint(125, 75);
  myShape.addPoint(25, 75);
  smooth();

// img2.filter(INVERT);
 size(img.width, img.height);
}

void draw(){

  background(255);
  stroke(0);
  myShape.display();

  img2.mask(myShape);
  image(img2,0,0);

}


class CustomShape extends Polygon {

  void display() {
    stroke(0);
    fill(0);
    beginShape();
    for (int i=0; i<npoints; i++) {
      vertex(xpoints[i], ypoints[i]); 
    }
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this code will give me an error: `The method mask(int[]) in the type PImage is not applicable for the arguments (Masking_image_1.CustomShape)`

Is this even possible to get the same result as my first code, but then with the use of a custom shape? And how can I solve that?

If there are any questions left, please let me know. Above code will work inside Processing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your error says it all: the `mask()` function does not know what to do with a `CustomShape` parameter. The parameter needs to be a `PImage` or a mask array. More info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_mask_.html).

To use your custom shape, what you want to do is draw that custom shape to a `PGraphics` (which is a subclass of `PImage`), and then use that `PGraphics` as the mask. You'd do that using the `createGraphics()` function. Again, more info can be found in [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/).